# Send POST request gluon

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I looked up the gluon doc for gluon connect [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/2.0.1/)

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.create()
        .method("GET")
        .host("https://api.stackexchange.com")
        .path("/2.2/questions/36243147")
        .queryParam("order", "desc")
        .queryParam("sort", "activity")
        .queryParam("site", "stackoverflow");

// retrieve an object from the DataProvider
GluonObservableObject<Question> question = DataProvider.retrieveObject(restClient.createObjectDataReader(Question.class));
```

how do we send with POST with JSON body like

```
{
"username":"wwh"
}
```

and get the string response.

thank you.

Comment: See [RestClient javadoc](https://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/javadoc/1.5.0/com/gluonhq/connect/provider/RestClient.html#dataString-java.lang.String-). Set method to POST.  Set [dataString](https://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/javadoc/1.5.0/com/gluonhq/connect/provider/RestClient.html#dataString-java.lang.String-) to the string form of your json.  Set [contentType](https://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/javadoc/1.5.0/com/gluonhq/connect/provider/RestClient.html#contentType-java.lang.String-) to `application/json`.  No form data or queryParam. I’ve never used the api, but that should work.

Comment: If it were me, I would use the [JDK http api](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/recipes.html#jsonPost) + [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) for this task.  Dealing with raw json strings is a pain, better to use a library that helps with that.  You could integrate Jackson use with the gluon api if you prefer that over the jdk http api.

Comment: I am not sure how you get the string response.  Maybe you need to use `createObjectDataReader(String.class)` and create your own StringDataProvider subclass of the DataProvider interface, but maybe there is a simpler method.

Comment: thanks! @jewelsea will try both methods and come back to update which works best

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the suggestion. JDK http works. i am getting an error after deployment on android its not connecting to the internet

Comment: Sorry, I can’t help with Android deployment.  Perhaps contact Gluon support about that.